# create a related row if no related row exists

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables with a one-to-many relationship.

I want to find all rows in the 'one' table which do not have a row in the 'many' table and add a single row in the 'many' table for each one.

How can I edit my query to achieve this?

```sql
INSERT INTO many_table SET 
    id = ( SELECT id 
           FROM one_table 
           JOIN many_table ON one_table.id = many_table.related_id 
           WHERE many_table.related_id is null
         ) 
    name = 'george'
```

Comment: would something like this work

INSERT INTO many_table

SET

id = ( SELECT id FROM one_table JOIN many_table ON one_table.id = many_table.related_id WHERE many_table.related_id is null)

name = 'george'

Comment: Providing a [repro] is the best place to start for questions on query help. You can [see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbebca44275d3d452f2fafca95fe0996) that there's a syntax error in what you've suggested in comments. I suggest playing with the fiddle and adding details based on that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is `name = 'george'` is doing but assume it's part of the filtering in `WHERE` clause.

```
INSERT INTO many_table (id, name)
SELECT o.id, o.name
FROM one_table o
LEFT JOIN many_table m ON m.related_id = o.id
WHERE o.name = 'george' AND m.id IS NULL
```

Comment: *but assume it's part of the filtering in WHERE clause.* I think it is an expression in SET (simply comma is lost) - 'george' is a value which must be inserted into NOT NULL field as a default value which is not set or is wrongly set in table structure.

Comment: I was unclear with the name = 'george' bit

what i was trying to show is code which would read a list of IDs from the one_table and for each one create a row in the many_table filling in the many_tables related_id field every time

the name = george was supposed to add the value george to a name column (which i previously did not mention) to every new row created in the many table

Comment: @megaman Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO many_table(id,name)

 SELECT  id ,'george'
           FROM one_table
           LEFT JOIN many_table ON one_table.id = many_table.related_id 
           WHERE many_table.related_id is null
```

Comment: How does this differ from the other answer?